# Is it possible to bind datasource of a jTable in java, like we do in DataGridView in c#?

Tags: c#, java, swing, datagridview

In c# , we can easily bind data to DataGridView using datasource property, like in this example:

```
    List <customer> custList = getCustomerList();
    myDataGridView.DataSource = custList ;
```

customers info like id, name, age and other attributes will automatically appear in suitable way in DataGridView component.
Is it possible to do the same in jTable, in java? how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In swing, you can create a table model and bind it to the JTable by its constructor:

```
JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
```

or by the setter method:

```
table.setModel(tableModel);
```

For the table model, you can create a custom one by extending `AbstractTableModel`. See:

- [Java Tutorial: Creating a Table Model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data).

Comment: In the example shown in the question, after I create a table model that is compatible with customer info, can I then bind the data of the customer list to the table like setting datasource in DataGridView in c# ??

Comment: @T-D Add new data to the data model because it's already bound to the JTable, i.e. your data model could have a method like `addMoreRows()`.

Comment: @T-D if you implement your own `TableModel` it can do anything you want